# Hate speech text data

Tags: data-request, corpora, classification

Where can I find a collection of hate speech articles and texts? I have tried using [hate speech and offensive language from github](https://github.com/t-davidson/hate-speech-and-offensive-language) but I am looking for long pieces of text (>~160 characters).

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine has indexed the text of Nazi and white supremacist message boards, such as Stormfront and VNN.  You can download the WARC's (snapshot compilations of the websites, with all their pages and assets) from those sites and then scrape the text.